# How to make partial update in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, update

I have two general questions how to show updates content and how to make partial update for example I want to update only nginx and don't touch other environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more traditional way to show upgrades without running them is `apt-get upgrade -s`

Another useful tool is `apt-show-versions` which will show "upgradeable" in the 2nd field if it needs an upgrade.

As with SvW's post, run `apt-get update` before both.

Answer (score 3):

To display list of available upgrades:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

and hit `n` to not actually upgrade.

```
apt-get changelog <packagename>
```

will list the changelog, if available.

To upgrade just one package:

```
apt-get install <packagename>
```

will install or upgrade just this package.

Note however that this might fail if an update is dependent on other updated packages.